# Best practice for unique constraint validation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

Coming from `Django` and `DRF` unique key validation is a piece of cake.
I'm trying to understand what is the best practice to this kind of validation.

I have some keys that need to be unique within the db table, but I can't figure out how to do so.
I looked for answer in pydantic's repo and they are say it is a bad practice to have a validator on the schema which queries the database and checks for duplicate.

so, what is the best practice to validate a unique key value?

```py
   # crud create
    def create(self, db: Session, obj: CreateSchemaType) -> ModelType:
        obj_data = jsonable_encoder(obj)
        db_obj = self.model(**obj_data)
        db.add(db_obj)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_obj)
        return db_obj
    
    # model
    class Company(Base):
        __tablename__ = "companies"
    
        id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, index=True)
    
        name = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)
        business_number = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)
        carrier_license_exp_date = Column(Date)
        professional_manager = Column(JSON, nullable=False)
    
        address = Column(JSON)
        contact = Column(JSON)
        email = Column(String)
        fax_number = Column(String)
        phone_number = Column(String)

    # schema
    class CompanyBase(BaseModel):
        name: str
        business_number: str
        professional_manager: ProfessionalManager
    
        carrier_license_exp_date: date | None
        contact: Contact | None = None
        address: Address | None = None
        phone_number: str | None = None
        fax_number: str | None = None
        email: EmailStr | None = None

    # endpoint
    @router.post(
        "/",
        status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
        response_model=schemas.Company,
        response_model_exclude_none=True,
    )
    async def create_company(
        company_obj: schemas.CompanyCreate,
        db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db),
    ) -> Any:
        company = crud.company.create(db=db, obj=company_obj)
        return company
```

example case:
The values of the keys `name` and `business_number` should be unique.

Comment: IMO, the "best practice" would be to drop the existing indexes on those two columns and re-create them as unique indexes.

Answer (score 4):

As Gord says, the best practice is to let the database handle those kinds of constraints. That way you can be sure your data is consistent, no matter how it ends up in the database (even with pydantic validation, someone might e.g. want to import a list of companies later and forget to use that specific validation).

Also, since you don't have the entire database in memory, you're gonna have to run a database query either way, so first checking if the data is OK with a `select` query and then inserting would result in two database calls instead of one, and more code to maintain.

See [this part of the SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint) for examples. In your example, it would be:

```py
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "companies"
    
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, index=True)
    
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    business_number = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    ...
```

Or, if the combination of `name` and `business_number` should be unique:

```py
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint

class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "companies"
    
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, index=True)
    
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    business_number = Column(String, nullable=False)
    ...

    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('name', 'business_number', name='_name_business_number_uc'),
    )
```